# How to get the cell value by column name?

Tags: c#, excel

my code below works fine but how to specify by column name?

```
for (int resultFiltered = 1; resultFiltered <= filteredRange.Areas.Count; areaId++)
{
  Range areaRange = filteredRange.Areas.Item(resultFiltered);
  string studentID = areaRange.Cells[1, 1].Value2; //How to specify column name?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can substitute the column number for the column letter.

Example:

```
object rangeObject = activeWorksheet.Cells[3, "W"];

Range range = (Range)rangeObject;

object rangeValue = range.Value2;

string cellValue = rangeValue.ToString();
```

Or if this helps, in the Excel file that I am accessing, I named the cell “W5” to “overflow5”:

```
Range topExcel = activeWorksheet.get_Range("overflow5", Type.Missing);

topExcel.Select();

string cellValue = topExcel.Value2.ToString();
```